# Why am i getting this error '.class' expected?

Tags: java, class

im trying to create a program but im getting some errors that I cant eliminate. can someone give me a hand please?

```
        import java.util.Scanner;

class julianDate {
    long year;
    long month;
    long day;
    long EPOCHYEAR;


      julianDate() {
      }


long returnJulianEpochDays(long year, long month, long day){
long yearCounter = EPOCHYEAR;
long total = 0;

while (yearCounter < year){

total += returnDaysInYear(yearCounter);

yearCounter += 1;

 }
  total += returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day);
  return total;
  }

}

 public class julianDateNew {



    }
```

ERRORS:

These are the errors i get when i compile my program:

```
/Users/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/src/julianDateNew.java:25: '.class' expected
  total += returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day);

/Users/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/src/julianDateNew.java:25: ';' expected
  total += returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day);

/Users/vlopezlama/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/src/julianDateNew.java:25: <identifier> expected
  total += returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day);

/Users/NetBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/src/julianDateNew.java:25: not a statement
  total += returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day);

/Users/etBeansProjects/JavaApplication1/src/julianDateNew.java:25: ';' expected
  total += returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day);
```

Comment: This is an example of why style, format, and readability matter.  This ugly code is unintelligible and hard to read.  No wonder there are compiler errors.

Comment: A good beginner's book on Java or the tutorials on oracle's site would be a good place to start. And use an IDE.

Comment: Off-topic, but a tip about posting questions (and maintaining your own code). No doubt you've seen example code around the place, and it is nicely formatted with appropriate indentation. Take a look at your code above - the indentation is all over the place, there are multiple blank lines etc.  This makes it hard for us to look at your code and see what's going on.  Also, the standard Java practice for naming classes is to use `UppercaseStartingCamelCase`.  You'll get more help from the community if you take the time to ensure that your code is formatted appropriately. :-)

Comment: Hey thanks @GregKopff I will take a look. I wish there is more nice people in this website like you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809878

Answer (score 1):

This declaration doesn't make sense:

```
total += returnJulianDate(long year, long month, long day);
```

Since you're making a method call to `returnJulianDate`, you only want to pass the variables that are declared to that type:

```
total += returnJulianDate(year, month, day);
```

Now, if the method `returnJulianDate` doesn't exist, then you've got another issue to tackle.

Comment: Although this is one of the necessary changes, it's not enough; `returnJulianDate` doesn't appear to exist as a method, among other compilation errors.

Comment: Assuredly there might be more, but IntelliJ only decided to choke on that declaration.  Depending on how the file is laid out, then there may be more problems, but from what I see, that declaration is the most prominent issue.